# Innovation error covariance decreasing but state error covariance inceasing

Tags: estimation, kalman-filter, stochastic-filtering

I am trying to implement Kalman Filter to estimate some random variables. I see that for the system I am using, the innovation error is zero for all times and the innovation error covariance matrix is getting smaller over time. But the state error covariance matrix keeps getting bigger. It seems pretty intriguing to me and I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have decreasing innovation error covariance but increasing state error covariance for all states?

Here are the equations for prediction and measurement update. $a = 0.01, b = 0.1$ and $R_1(t), R_2(t)$ are rotation matrices which are functions of time, $t$ , $C_1 \in R^{3\times 1}, C_2 \in R^{3\times 1}$ and $s$ is a variable:

Prediction: $X_{k+1} = F_kX_k + \nu_k \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \nu_k\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, Q\right)$

$F_k = \left[1.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0   
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ aR_1[0][0] \ \ aR_1[0][1] \ \ aR_1[0][2] \ \ 0.0 \ \ -aC_1[2]
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ aR_1[1][0] \ \ aR_1[1][1] \ \ aR_1[1][2] \ \ aC_1[2] \ \ 0.0
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0 \ \ aR_1[2][0] \ \ aR_1[2][1] \ \ aR_1[2][2] \ \ -aC_1[1] \ \ aC_1[0]
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ R_2[0][0] \ \ R_2[0][1] \ \ R_2[0][2] \ \ bR_1[1][0] \ \ -bR_1[0][0]
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ R_2[1][0] \ \ R_2[1][1] \ \ R_2[1][2] \ \ bR_1[1][1] \ \ -bR_1[0][1]
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ R_2[2][0] \ \ R_2[2][1] \ \ R_2[2][2] \ \ bR_1[1][2] \ \ -bR_1[0][2]
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0 \ \ 0.0
\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 1.0\right]$

Observations($z\in R^{3 \times 1}$):

$z = \left[sC_2[0] + sX[5] + C_2[0]X[0] + X[5]X[0] \\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ sC_2[1] + sX[6] + C_2[1]X[0] + X[6]X[0] \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ sC_2[2] + sX[7] + C_2[2]X[0] + X[7]X[0]\right]$

Update:
$z_k = H_kX_k + \eta_k \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \eta_k\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, R\right) \\
H_k = \left[C_2[0]+X[5] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ s+X[0] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C_2[1]+X[6] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ s+X[0] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ C_2[2]+X[7] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0 \ \ s+X[0] \ \ 0.0 \ \ 0.0\right]$

$X[0]$ may be unobservable. But I am interested in the variance of $X[5]$ and it diverges with time. The values of $R$ and $Q$ that I am using are:
$Q = \text{diag}\left(\left[1e-4, 1e-4, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-8, 1e-8\right]\right)$

$R = \text{diag}\left(\left[1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6\right]\right)$

Comment: Is your system observable?

Comment: One of the states may not be observable. But other states are. But the state error covariance is increasing for all states.

Comment: Hi: you should write down the observation equation and system equation that you are using  ( atleast generically ) because what happens can depend on what version of the KF you are using.  Also, the innovation error being zero for all times sounds odd to me.

Comment: Please see the updated equations.